# Implement setstat and bind variables

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I'm trying to get and display 2 variable values from another dart file, ("int myId" and "String myMenu") , these variables are updated with every "onTap" widget, my code works, but only if i do a "hot reload", i think that i need to put a "setstate" somewhere, but i'm having difficulty to implement it.

I think the problem is there, my widget text returns "null" to me, but if I hit the menu button and do a "hot reload", it's ok.

**displayText.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './menu.dart';

class display extends StatefulWidget {
  int myId;
  String myMenu;
  display(this.myId, this.myMenu);
  @override
  _displayState createState() => _displayState();
}

class _displayState extends State<display> {
  Future myVarUsed() async {
    //Each press on the button return the value
    setState(() {
      print('myIdDsiplay: ${widget.myId}'); // null
      print('myMenuDisplay : ${widget.myMenu}'); // null
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myVarUsed();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 250,
      width: 250,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text('My ID is : ${widget.myId}'),
          Text('My menu is : ${widget.myMenu}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This file contains the menu inside a scrollbar, each button return the ID and the name (of the button)  and store it in 2 variable ("int myId" and "String myMenu") that i want to pass.

**menu.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './mylist.dart';
import './displayText.dart';

class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  static int myId;
  static String myMenu;
  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  Container scrollList() {
    final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 1, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 0.35);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 90,
      child: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: listdata.length,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: gestureDetector_Ontap(index),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  GestureDetector gestureDetector_Ontap(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Menu.myId = listdata[index].id;
        Menu.myMenu = listdata[index].menuObj;
        display(Menu.myId, Menu.myMenu);

        print('myIDMenu ${Menu.myId}');
        print('myMenuMenu ${Menu.myMenu}');
      },

      child: Container(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        child: Text(
          '${listdata[index].menuObj}',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: scrollList(),
    );
  }
}
```

This file contains my list and his class

**mylist.dart**

```
class listModel {
  int id;
  String menuObj;
  listModel(this.id, this.menuObj);
}

List listdata = [
  listModel(0, 'Menu01'),
  listModel(1, 'Menu02'),
  listModel(2, 'Menu03'),
  listModel(3, 'Menu04'),
  listModel(4, 'Menu05')
];
```

And the container

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './menu.dart';
import './displayText.dart';
import './mylist.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Menu(),
              display(Menu.myId, Menu.myMenu),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

You're defining `Menu` this way:

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  static int myId;
  static String myMenu;

  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}
```

When your app starts, `myId` and `myMenu` are uninitialized variables, therefore they're implicitely set to null.

---

Inside `_MyHomePageState`, you call

```
display(Menu.myId, Menu.myMenu)
```

Since you haven't initialized `Menu.myId` and `Menu.myMenu` yet, they're still null.

---

When you tap the GestureDetector, you initialize `Menu.myId` and `Menu.myMenu` this way:

```
Menu.myId = listdata[index].id;
Menu.myMenu = listdata[index].menuObj;
display(Menu.myId, Menu.myMenu);

print('myIDMenu ${Menu.myId}');
print('myMenuMenu ${Menu.myMenu}');
```

Now, `Menu.myId` and `Menu.myMenu` are defined to non-null values. However, this **will not** update the Container's `display(Menu.myId, Menu.myMenu)`, so they'll still be null, you need to update it by yourself.

### The solution

I've added comments through the code, pointing a better approach:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Avoid displaying the warning "Name types using UpperCamelCase."
class Display extends StatefulWidget {
  // Make these fields final and the constructor const
  final int myId;
  final String myMenu;
  
  const Display(this.myId, this.myMenu);
  
  @override
  _DisplayState createState() => _DisplayState();
}

// Avoid displaying the warning "Name types using UpperCamelCase."
class _DisplayState extends State<Display> {
  // You don't need this Future nor this initState
  // 
  // Future myVarUsed() async {
  //   setState(() {
  //     print('myIdDsiplay: ${widget.myId}'); // null
  //     print('myMenuDisplay : ${widget.myMenu}'); // null
  //   });
  //  }
  // 
  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   myVarUsed();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 250,
      width: 250,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text('My ID is : ${widget.myId}'),
          Text('My menu is : ${widget.myMenu}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  // Avoid using mutable static fields
  // static int myId;
  // static String myMenu;
  
  // To simplify, you can add a onChanged callback to 
  // be triggered whenever you change `myId` and `myMenu`
  final void Function(int myId, String myMenu) onChanged;
  
  const Menu({this.onChanged});
  
  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  Container scrollList() {
    final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 1, keepPage: true, viewportFraction: 0.35);

    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 90,
      child: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: listdata.length,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: gestureDetectorOntap(index),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // Avoid displaying the warning "Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase."
  GestureDetector gestureDetectorOntap(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // Make these local variables
        int myId = listdata[index].id;
        String myMenu = listdata[index].menuObj;
        
        // Call the `onChanged` callback
        widget.onChanged(myId, myMenu);
        
        // This widget is being thrown away
        // display(Menu.myId, Menu.myMenu);

        print('myIDMenu $myId');
        print('myMenuMenu $myMenu');
      },

      child: Container(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        child: Text(
          '${listdata[index].menuObj}',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: scrollList(),
    );
  }
}

// Avoid the warning "Name types using UpperCamelCase."
class ListModel {
  // You can make these fields final and the constructor const
  final int id;
  final String menuObj;
  
  const ListModel(this.id, this.menuObj);
}

// You can make this list const to avoid modifying it unintentionally later
const List<ListModel> listdata = [
  ListModel(0, 'Menu01'),
  ListModel(1, 'Menu02'),
  ListModel(2, 'Menu03'),
  ListModel(3, 'Menu04'),
  ListModel(4, 'Menu05')
];

void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Create fields to store the current `myId` and current `myMenu`
  int myId;
  String myMenu;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Add the `onChanged` callback here, updating this widget state
              Menu(
                onChanged: (newMyId, newMyMenu) {
                  setState(() {
                    myId = newMyId;
                    myMenu = newMyMenu;
                  });
                }
              ),
              // Access the current values here
              Display(myId, myMenu),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code and for these good explanations Enzo .